# Getting error when trying to install compass npm ERR! Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: node.js, linux, gruntjs, compass, grunt-contrib-compass

I'm trying to install compass onto my hosting server and I keep getting the above error fed back to the shell.

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I've install node, grunt, contrib-watch, and contrib-uglify after some work arounds. The last dependency I need is compass.

I don't see any errors in the logs until I get to the very bottom:

```
4924 error Linux 3.12.18-clouder0
4925 error argv "/home/joshuag3/bin/node" "/home/joshuag3/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-contrib-watch" "--save-dev"
4926 error node v4.4.1
4927 error npm  v2.14.20
4928 error code EPEERINVALID
4929 error peerinvalid The package grunt@1.0.1 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
4929 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-contrib-uglify@0.2.7 wants grunt@~0.4.0
4930 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I am very very new to node and this type of thing. If there is a solution please overly explain.

Answer (score 0):

Check out google - on github there are plenty similar issues. Maybe you will find there your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `cmd` and Go to your root User folder such as `C:\Users\User` and run `npm install -g npm@latest`

this will update your npm to the latest version. Try your install again and should work fine now.

Additionally, you can use `npm audit fix` after the  `npm install -g npm@latest`